# Error IOException downloading an image in java

Tags: java, image, url

I'm trying to download an imagen in java,using a function,
here is my code to send the function

```
saveImage(newString, folder.toString());
```

then, this is my function saveImage

```
public static void saveImage(String imageUrl,String folderpath) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
    //String destName = folder;
    //System.out.println(destName);

    InputStream is = url.openStream();
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(folderpath);
    byte[] b = new byte[2048];
    int length;
    while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
        os.write(b, 0, length);
    }
    is.close();
    os.close();
}
```

i tried from links here at stackoverflow, but anything works, all the time i got a

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL
```

how can i fix it? the Exception, thank you

Comment: You seriously can't google "HTTP 403" ?

Comment: if i haven't tried it, i wouldn't post this..

Comment: Well then clarify your question - what didn't you understand about the information available "what's that?" is not a very good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the code to fix it, if anyone want to use it.

```
public static void saveImage(String imageUrl, File folder, String m) throws IOException {
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            folder.mkdirs();
            System.out.println("si quedo con el if folderpath----" + folder);
        }
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        //String destName = folder;
        //System.out.println(destName);
        m = m + ".jpg";
        //final URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        final HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");
        final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(connection.getInputStream());
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File(m));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A 403 Forbidden HTTP status return code from a web server indicates that the server can be reached but refuses to take any action due to the web server being configured to deny access, for whatever reason, to the requested resource.

So there's nothing wrong with the code that you showed us, it's to do with the configuration of the web server that you're trying to get the image from.

Try using an [`Authenticator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Authenticator.html) in order to set the authenticator default that will be used for all requests. You will need a user name and password.

It can be used something like this:

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
 @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
         return new PasswordAuthentication(
   "user", "password".toCharArray());
        }
});
```